# Kernel generic vs low-latency vs Zen

Tags: kernel, performance

I would like to move from Windows to Ubuntu 14 LTS and i would like to ask you which kernel should i use. I will be using PC for surfing, programming, livestreaming (twitch), recording videos on YouTube, 3D modeling and gaming.

I would like to ask you which kernel has the biggest performance for gaming, programming, recording, etc..

And the last question is, what about Zen kernel? I heard that it has quite big performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you install Ubuntu 14.04 now, it will be 14.04.3.

[Download-Link -> Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS - 64 bit version](http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-14.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso)

This edition comes with kernel 3.19, which runs great.

In April Ubuntu 16.04 will be released with kernel 4.4.

It is recommended to stick with the installed kernel.

The kernel is a special version, modified for Ubuntu.

This guarantees maximum stability and performance.

Comment: What about livestreaming, recording videos on YouTube? People are saying that low-latency is for recording better :)

Comment: @tomsk : The most important thing of all is the hardware you are using - when you are having more or less modern hardware, everything will work as it should when the system is installed properly ... so there is no reason to fiddle around with other kernels. In case that you use very old hardware, maybe you have less performance then, but changing the kernel will not help much anyway. The only thing that could improve performance on these machines, is to install a lightweight desktop environment such as lxde or xfce. :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you know you can use more than one kernel on a distribution?

If you want to try different kernels, is always a good idea to have a back-up one that you know that it works (the default kernel of the distro is perfect) just in case.

But, in my experience, for anything related to realtime (so that would include if you broadcast livestream or record professional music) go for lowlatency kernel (distro like [ubuntustudio](https://ubuntustudio.org/) have them set and ready)

for a daily use (surfing, typing, etc) a regular kernel is perfect.

I don't know about zen.

Comment: Thank you for answer, but im not going to record professional music, just videos to YouTube and twitch, audio bitrate about 192kbps at 44khz and video bitrate about 15mbit per second

Comment: Then I wouldn't bother to try a real time kernel. Standard one should be more than enough.